# How to write query summing?

Tags: sql

i have table with 2 columns: date and points.  I want to create a query that will return the sum of points for all days, including today.  This is to generate a chart of points earned up and until today.

Edit: I think my question was clearer before ews edited it :)

With data like that

```
2012-01-01    1
2012-01-02    1
2012-01-02    2     same day as above (we can have many records for one day, you can think of it as a result of one game on that day)
2012-01-03   -1
```

I would like to see the result:

```
2012-01-01    1
2012-01-02    4  (1+1+2)
2012-01-03    3  (1+1+2-1)
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008. If you know how to do it in LINQ to Entities that would be great.

Comment: In other words just a total SUM of all the points, or the SUM of points for each day?

Comment: Which DBMS? (PostgreSQL? MySQL? SQL-Server? Oracle?)

Comment: The question changed now. What do you need? A simple sum or a "running sum", so a cummulative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need cummulative, you should try this:

**Edit:**

```
SELECT 
Date,
(SELECT SUM(Point) FROM A WHERE Date <= MainTable.Date) AS Points
FROM A MainTable
GROUP BY Date
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae7f8/2) to test it.

Comment: I edited my question. There may be many records for each day. I added group by date to your query and it's perfect now. Maybe you know if it's possible to do it in LINQ to Entities?

Comment: I knew it must be something simple but couldn't find solution myself. Stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Some DBMSes have a better way to do this by using window functions, but here's a query that should work in most any SQL database:

```
SELECT t1.date,
       SUM(t2.points) AS points_to_date
  FROM table_name t1
  JOIN table_name t2
    ON t2.date <= t1.date
 ORDER
    BY t1.date
;
```

Comment: It's invalid SQL - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26ac8/3. I added group by but then it returns wrong results. But still it helped me a bit so I upvote.

Comment: @Peri: Oh, wow, whoops, sorry! I should have tested first, or failing that, at least posted a disclaimer that I hadn't tested.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this is with a new query for each day.

```
dateVariable = "2012-09-06"
SELECT Sum(points) From table_name WHERE Date<=dateVariable;
```

Obviously you would need to iterate over all the days to do this, changing dateVariable each time.

Comment: This is the procedural way to do it. That was the one solution I had in mind but it's bad. I don't even know how I would call that and return sums for all days in my database.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the question you want a running sum of points, so that each date has the sum of points of all dates less than that date. If so, take a look at the running total section of [this article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3112381/SQL-Server-Calculating-Running-Totals-Subtotals-and-Grand-Total-Without-a-Cursor.htm).